# stopPropagation onclick not working in nested list

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

i have the following function to swap images on the click of a ul in a nested list, but it doesnt stop bubbling up the list..

```
function bimageswap (step) {
    step.stopPropagation;
    realstep = parseInt(step) + 1;
    nextsteps = realstep + 1;
    for (iss = nextsteps;iss <= 5; iss++) {
        document.getElementById("step" + iss).className = 'step' + iss;
        alert(iss);
    }
    document.getElementById("step" + realstep).className = 'step' + realstep + 'a';
/*$("#step2").css( 'background-image', 'images/adtl_prodimg/discs/step1_.png');*/
    return false;
}
```

it is called like this:

```
<ul onclick='return bimageswap("4")'>
```

i tried the return because it is what i found in another answer but it still doesnt work. i would greatly appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: step.stopPropagation; - did you missed () after function name only here or in your code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stopPropagation` method is in the `event` object, you can't call it on a string. You are also missing the parentheses, so it would just get the `stopPropagation` property from the string (which returns `undefined`) and discard it.

Send the event object from the event handler to the function:

```
<ul onclick="bimageswap(event, '4');">
```

Use the event object in the function:

```
function bimageswap(event, step) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...
```